# Trying to move the default Django admin app to another base url

Tags: django, python-3.x

Using Django 2.1, I need to point the default admin app to a database dynamically determined by a URL prefix (using a middleware+a DB router). Something like /admin/. when I tried that, the admin code complained about a missing parameter ('db' obviously). ideas? pointers?

```
 urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:org>/admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('<str:org>/', include('Management.urls')),
 ]
```

The error I get:

```
index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'org'
```

Comment: If you got an error, you should post the whole thing, along with the actual code you used.

Comment: Here is the modified patterns:
<pre><code>
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:org>/admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('<str:org>/', include('Management.urls')),
] </code></pre>
The error:

TypeError at /TrackerIQ/admin/
index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'org'
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/TrackerIQ/admin/
Django Version:  2.1
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  
index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'org'